# Avoiding declaring nonsensical Error instance

Tags: haskell, error-handling

I have a custom error type with various constructors, let's call it `MyError`:

```
data MyError = ConditionA String | ConditionB String | ConditionC String
```

The constructors categorise the type of error, and the strings provide additional detail.
I want to use my error type in the `Either` monad, for example I want a function like

```
myFunction :: a -> Either MyError a
```

Inside myFunction, I want to use the `maybeToEither` function from `Data.Either.Utils` in MissingH:

```
maybeToEither :: MonadError e m => e -> Maybe a -> m a
```

But ghc tells me that to do this, I have to make `MyError` and instance of `Error`. This seems to come down to the fact that `MonadError` requires `m` to be a monad, and that the monad instance for `Either e` requires `Error e` because of `fail`:

```
instance (Error e) => Monad (Either e) where
    return        = Right
    Left  l >>= _ = Left l
    Right r >>= k = k r
    fail msg      = Left (strMsg msg)
```

How then can I avoid making a non-sensical `Error` instance declaration for `MyError`?

I noticed that the authors of `Database.MongoDB.Query` had the same problem with their `Failure` datatype (which also has multiple constructors and therefore no sensible `Error` instance), and their solution was to treat the use of `fail` as an error:

```
instance Error Failure where strMsg = error
```

Is that my best option here?

Comment: Why is this a nonsensical instance? You're telling GHC how to use your type for storing an error message, that seems pretty reasonable to me.

Comment: Because it has multiple constructors, you can't choose the correct one based on a call to strMsg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use the MissingH library for this. Just use the base library, which is bundled with every version of the GHC compiler. Unless your code explicitly requires use of the `MonadError` class (from the mtl library) for some essential reason, you can then avoid using that class, and thereby avoid the need for an `Error` instance on your error type.

Starting with version 4.3 of the base library - released in November 2010 - the standard `Monad` instance of `Either e` does *not* require `e` to be an instance of `Error`. So you can just include the line

```
import Control.Monad.Instances ()
```

at the top of your module, and then use the type `Either MyError` as a `Monad` at will.

Use this function instead of MissingH's `maybeToEither`:

```
maybeToEither :: e -> Maybe a -> Either e a
maybeToEither e = maybe (Left e) Right
```

If you really do need the `MonadError` instance for `Either`, you'll have to modify your `MyError` type to provide an `Error` instance in some artificial way. See @jozefg's answer for some more detailed suggestions about how to do that. Even then, I personally wouldn't bother pulling in the whole MissingH library just for something simple like this.

Comment: Yitz's answer is good. You might also want to look at the 'errors' package

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 choices

1. Add a case to `MyError`

   ```
   data MyError = FailCase String
                | ...
   ```

   It's simple, bu kinda ugly.
2. Pass it to `error`

   This is what the dd for the DB handle, but runtime errors suck so perhaps this should be avoided.
3. Wrap `MyError` in a `Either` (or `Maybe`, or some other thing to handle the error case).

   ```
   type MyErrorMonad = Either (Either String MyError)
   ```

   and then you simply have to define a few synonyms. It's more typing, but probably the most conceptually clean. And it forces you to explicitly handle the case in which `fail` is called.

   ```
   caseA = Right . CaseA
   ....
   ```

   and

   ```
   instance Error (Either String b) where strMsg = Left
   ```